# Publishing Cache issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, uls, blob-cache

We are using SharePoint 2013 and enable blob cache on all our server. Which is working good.

Suddenly I was start getting error

`An error occured in the blob cache.  The exception message was 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.`

In ULS Log Viewer When I double click on it I will get file name. Which is very good and I will try open that page correct the URL of the file. For example like some css is reference with wrong URL or some image is not published that I will published.

But I don't know that this file in which page reference wrong, so I can go there correct it.

Kindly can somebody help that how to find page name

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This was a Known Issue in 2010 and they fixed it with December 2013 CU.

I am surprised to see the same issue in 2013, did you apply the latest CU to your Farm.

Before applying the Latest Update, i would try to flush the Blob Cache.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```

Comment: Reason for down vote is you giving wrong advice. It is not bug but as I explain you in my question that when I give wrong reference of css file in my file or when I don't publish some. Cache will throw file not found. error But I wanted to know in which Page that file is not reference correct.